# can some one give me a sample gzip code for htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, gzip

I'm keen to get started experimenting with gzip, but like i used to find php.net when i first started learning php, the apache documentation confuses me a bit. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html

I'd really appreciate a sample htaccess file to have a look at if anyone's got one?

Also are there things which should be changed in the httpd.conffile instead of htaccess if I'm enabling gzipping server-wide?

Sorry i'm a newb with apache!

---

edit:

so i enable mod_deflate in the httpd.conf and then putting the following into an ht access file will work (as an example)?

```
<Location />
# Insert filter
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
# BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
# the above regex won't work. You can use the following
# workaround to get the desired effect:
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</Location>
```

Comment: What’s wrong with the sample configuration in the mod_deflate docs (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html#recommended)?

Comment: Is there anything in particular you don't understand in the docs?

Comment: That code is intended to be used either in the server or a virtual host configuration (see context of `<Location>`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location).

Comment: thanks gumbo that's helpful, i got this this page from there which makes things much clearer: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html re what <location> is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable gzip either in Apache, with mod_deflate or with PHP. The module itself must be activated in Apache's main config file, though you can decide which files are compressed on a per-directory basis using .htaccess files (unless the main configuration forbids with `AllowOverride None` or similar). The link you included provides examples.

You can also enable it only in PHP by adding `zlib.output_compression = On` to your php.ini file.

Comment: thanks artefacto, i've updated my question, hopefully makes more sense!

Comment: is apache's main config file the httpd.conf file?

Comment: @Harol Yes it's the httpd.conf. And <Location> belongs in it, not in an .htaccess.